# Publishing ASP.Net MVC 4 application using Visual Studio Publish method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2012, publish

I am new to Web site deployment so please forgive me if this is already answered elsewhere ( I tried searching but could not figure it out).

I developed a very basic ASP.Net MVC 4 application with Visual Studio 2012 and now want to publish it on a Windows 7 computer in IIS. I tried using Visual Studio's Publish option with "File System" as Publish method. Output window shows publish was successful but I dont see my website listed in IIS Manager.

Then I went to IIS Manager manually and in Sites I chose "Add Website" to manually add the published site. Now I can browse the website in the browser. But I can not browse to this site from any other computer on the same network. Why is it so?

Comment: When you use publish to the file system you are asked to select a folder to publish to, did you check where the files where being published?

Comment: yes, i specified a directory in D:\ drive.

Comment: after the publish can you see the files in that folder?

Comment: yes. Files are there but I see nothing in IIS Manager. So I right clicked on "Sites" in IIS Manager and added the site manually by giving path to this folder.

Comment: Sounds like the publish method is working fine. This has nothing to do with VS. You need to put the files in a folder that people on your network can access. This is usually an InetPub folder, but you will need to ensure it is accessible on your network.

Comment: disabled the Fire Wall and it started working fine :)